# What are the steps of running a Java Swing application on Linux (not Ubuntu or Debian)?

Tags: java, linux, swing

I have written a simple Java Swing application (It shows one image.jpg and a 2 buttons in the `JFrame`). I have a Linux system that I want this Java Swing application to run on start.

I connected to my Linux device with SSH using Putty. I checked and Java is not installed.
I will install Java using RPM but when I typed `uname -m` it prompted `armv7l`. I checked and it is a 32 bit device. But also it is an ARM. Which RPM version of Java should I use?

I have searched and found that there is a way that creates Linux service from Java application. But that doesn't show any GUI.

I found that X and $DISPLAY have to be used to show GUI on Linux.

But I don't know what steps I should follow.

Could you point me to the right direction?

Edit: My linux system has a screen connected to it but not a keyboard. I installed Java for a 32-bit ARM by transferring Java JDK with SSH and `pscp`. I can now execute Java Console Applications. I checked and there is X.org server on my Linux system. When I typed `ps -A`, I saw that Xorg is running. Should I kill the current Xorg? How can I make the X server show my Java Swing GUI?

Comment: Are you using an X11 server on your Linux box?

Comment: Debug the following: (1) ability to run console Java applications like "Hello world", (2) ability to run non-Java GUI applications like `xcalc` (you will need either vncserver on remote computer or Xserver on your CLIENT computer (sic!)); if it is Windows it can be VcXsrv) in latter case $DISPLAY should point to client's IP), and (3) only after that try Java GUI apps. Java is portable, if it's runtime is installed, other things should work.

Comment: @Dims I have edited the post could you check and get back?

Comment: @Mehmet Do you have a black screen or a terminal on you screen ? Check my second edit on my answer. Try to run any graphical app, you can come on DM if needed.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, xterm worked after exporting the X server at 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find arm version of Java : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html
This Java 8 JDK, but you can also download the JRE.

You can install from the .rpm or just uncompress the tar.gz archive.

Concerning the graphical interface, you must install a X server, x.org is the most common one.
Be aware that an X server is just a server that runs over a terminal on a screen, but it doesn't do so much alone. You will not have a window with a taskbar and all.
But if I understand your requirements, it looks like it's what you are looking for. If you need more, you may want to install a window manager like XFCE.

As soon as you have installed x.org you should be able to run any graphical application. A X client needs the DISPLAY environment variable to know the server, by default it's `:0`, which is actually a short for `127.0.0.1:0`.
A quick check is to install xterm and try to run it.

Because x.org run over a terminal (you will have to run `startx` command), you will just get a black screen when it will work the first time (except if you added a default app or a window manager). To be able to run an application by hand, you have to switch terminal.
On linux you can have multiple terminal, to switch between them you can do `ctrl-alt-F*` (the function keys on top of the keyboard, I hope you don't have a mac keyboard). On many system, the first terminal is on F1, but sometimes the x server is run on F3.
Then a `DISPLAY=:0 xterm` must show a terminal on inside the x server.
You can also run the application from ssh, the point is to precise the display using the env var.

To install the X server, I suggest you to look the specific tutorial for your hardware (raspberry, beaglebone..). If you have an exotic hardware, try to follow any tutorial, but most of the time a simple `apt install xorg` is enough, but it's driver-less.

Good luck.

Edit:
I forgot. If you don't have a screen connected on your device, installing an X server onto the linux board is useless, you can run an X server on your computer and run X application through SSH `ssh -X toto@ip`.
But I guess you have a connected screen on your linux board.

Edit 2:
If you don't have a keyboard connected but you have a running x.org, you must be able to run xcalc, xterm ect from SSH by setting DISPLAY=:0 env var.

Answer (score 0):

To run a GUI application inside a Linux-based machine, the $DISPLAY should be defined to pass all GUI info.

So we have multiple ways to do that:

1- Connect a real Display:
So you will find the `$DISPLAY` environment variable defined, then you can run the GUI application.

2- Use SSH with X forwarding:
When you connect to a remote Linux system, ask it to forward the GUI operations buffer to your machine
`ssh -X run-my-gui-application.sh`

3- Fake the DISPLAY (**Hardware** solution):
By injecting small real hardware like a USB connector (not a display) then the operating system will assume there is a display, then the GUI app will run

4- Fake the DISPLAY (**Software** solution):
By installing a package to emulate the DISPLAY, for example, use [xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) lib:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb

# [GUI] headless mode
# ~FAKE DISPLAY~ number 88
nohup Xvfb :88 -ac & 
export DISPLAY=:88.0
```